# Copy operation on new OneDrive API

Tags: onedrive

I've been stumbling on this issue for a while. I'm trying to copy file which is located at OneDrive's folder into another folder within the same account. (i.e: from user's root folder to one of it's subfolder).

According to [OneDrive Copy API](http://onedrive.github.io/items/copy.htm), I need to call this REST API:

```
POST /drive/items/{item-id}/action.copy
```

where `{item-id}` is the file's id which I want to copy. For this request, I've using this content:

```
{
    "parentReference": {
        "id": [destination-folder-id]
    }
}
```

This http call was work just fine. I've got the desired result which is:

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Location: https://onedrive.com/monitor/[generated-alphanumeric-characters]
```

When I following the link at `Location` header, I got the async job status which is:

```
{
    "operation": "ItemCopy",
    "percentageComplete": 0,
    "status": "notStarted",
    "statusDescription": "Completed 0/0 files; 0/0 bytes"
}
```

The problem is, no matter how many times I wait and call this link, it gives the exact response, which it's `status` was `notStarted`. I also try to reproduce this using [OneDrive's API Console](https://apigee.com/OneDrive/embed/console/OneDrive) and it shows exact behaviors. I don't have any problem when copying an empty folder. This problem only occurs on files. Does anyone know why? Is there anything I should do to start that async job?

Comment: This is a bug we're in the process of investigating.  You can follow the issue here: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/18

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It seems the issue is fixed at April 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that no one knows about this problem. For now, I have to use the old OneDrive API (formerly SkyDrive API) only for this copy operation, like this example:

```
COPY https://apis.live.net/v5.0/file.a6b2a7e8f2515e5e.A6B2A7E8F2515E5E!126

Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "destination": "folder.a6b2a7e8f2515e5e.A6B2A7E8F2515E5E!114"
}
```

The things after file. and folder. is user id followed by item id (`file id` for the item or `folder id` for destination). Note that this only works on file. We cannot copy folder. If success, it will return a status code of `Created`.

Oh, and ... In order to use this API, we need to have `wl.skydrive_update` in the scope when authenticating our app.

I won't mark this answer as accepted answer since this is only a workaround for this issue. It does not solve the real problem.

UPDATE per April 12:
Ok. According to [this bug tracking](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/18#issuecomment-91037801), this API should working by now (the referenced comment are posted on April 10. So I'll mark this question as answered.